# How to cut a text after a number of chars and obtain text sporead on multiple rows?

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a very long text, and I need to cut the text after N chars, so that at the end I obtain a text, rendered on multiple rows, without any of the words being cut;

So, if a have a text with the lenght of a 1000 chars, which has been saved on 1 line, and I need to cut from 100 to 100 chars, at the end, I will get a text spread on 10 lines.

I tryed something, but I got stuck;

foreach does not work, the text is not seen a a array; also, i did not made sure to keep the words intact in my test;

Has anyone tryed this? Or is there any link with solution?

```
public static function cut_line_after_n_chars($str, $n = 70) {
    $result = '';
    $pos = 0;
    foreach ($str as $c) {
        $pos++;
        if ($pos == $n) {
            $result .= $c + '<br/>';
            $pos = 0;
        }
        else
            $result .= $c;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `$result .= $c + '<br/>';` this is definitely NOT going to work out for you. you cannot "add" strings like this. Seeing this is confusing, since you ARE using the concatenation operator (`.`) already.

Comment: I tryed to get a new result, by concat char by char;

Comment: yes, but you're not concatenating. try `echo 'a' + 'a'` and see what you get. you don't get `aa`, you get `0`.

Comment: As well, why are you not using http://php.net/wordwrap ? php can do this for you automatically.

Comment: If i have only a huge text, like 1000 chars, no spaces, will wordwrapp cut the text into lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need `wordwrap`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

This allows you to break a string into an array of pieces without cutting off words. You can then format these pieces as you like.

**EDIT**

If you still need each of your lines to be 100 characters, you can use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to add extra spaces onto each row.

Comment: 1. explode by space, count chars, make sure I count the spaces, make sure that the new chars do not exceed N

Comment: and what if i have a very long word? the wordwrap does not cut that word; someone entered a 1000 chars word in my db, and my interface get smaller and smaller as the word gets bigger; :))

Comment: Someone in the PHP documentation that Montgomery Jean linked actually addresses that very issue. [See this comment.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#102120)

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() function to get array of words from your string.

```
$words = explode( ' ', $str );

$length = 0;
foreach( $words as $word ) {
  // Your loop code goes here.
}
```

Comment: forget this answer, wordwrap() is better.